# Object as object property name Error?

Tags: javascript, properties

```
var a = {};
var b = new Object();
var c = new Object();
a[b] = 123;
a[c] = 456;
console.log(a[b]); //output is 456, why?
console.log(a[c]); //output is 456, why?
```

How does this work, `a[b]` output is 456, why?

Comment: Whole concept doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm guessing your object instantiation is being overwritten because just declaring, not initializing, either b or c as an object fixes it

Answer (score 3):

Since an object is being supplied as the object key, it is being converted to a string using toString().

```
var b = new Object();
console.log(b.toString());
[object Object]
```

Since, both `var b` and `var c` translate to `[object Object]`. The object references are treated as below:

```
a["[object Object]"] = 123;
a["[object Object]"] = 456;
```

The latest value for `[object Object]` is 456.

You can verify this by trying to print the value :

```
a["[object Object]"]
456
a[(new Object()).toString()]
456
```

Answer (score 0):

It **doesn't make sense**, but ...

```
var a = {};
var b = {}; // new Object();
var c = {}; // new Object();

a[b] = 123; // Object in object {'[object Object]': 123}
```

Now it will be **overwritten** with:

```
a[c] = 456; // Object in object {'[object Object': 456}
```

a[c] is **equal** to a[b];

```
console.log(a[b]); // Output is  456!
console.log(a[c]); // Output is  456!
```